# Git confusion, made many changes including deleting and renaming files in goorm, how to proceed

Tags: git, heroku, git-push

I am rewriting my personal website and have drastically changed the way the site works, which means I have deleted many of the old files that are not needed out of my goorm workspace (many files were moved to a CDN). I have been always doing the `git add`, `git commit -m` and `git push heroku master` steps when pushing any changes out to heroku to make the changes live, but I’m now confused about what to do after changing so much of the file structure. 
  When I do a

```
 git status
```

there are dozens of deleted files, I have changed so much, I almost think it would be better to wipe the git repo clean and start over. What is the best way to do this.?
  If I truly don’t want to revert to any previous versions, can I just delete the `.git` folder in my local goorm structure and start over with

```
git init
```

or is there a better way? The web dev course I watched explained very little about git and not sure If I could create some other "v2" branch that is the new file structure. I will not be going back to a previous version of this site since I drastically changed the way the entire site functions. 
Also, if I create a new git repo with `git init` and it has way less files than what is currently on heroku, do the files that were on heroku stay, or does a `git push` command overwrite everything that is at the target of the push.?
 Thanks for any info.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want delete the "old" git-repo and create a new repo with the current status and all changed files you can remove the `.git` folder.

```
cd repository-path/
rm -rf .git
```

(for deleting git repository on git-server [tutorial](https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-a-github-repository/))

after this you can create a *new* git repo in this path with

```
git init
git add . //with . you add all files
git commit -m "new repo cleaned old files"
git push
```

If you don't want ti delete the changed files make

```
git add . //with . you add all files 
git commit -m "cleaned current repo from old files"
git push
```

> Is there a better way?

I would not delete the current git repository, even if you never want to go back to the old version, because that's what git is made for. And at some point you might still be happy if you can't go back, who knows? Since git is a versioning system, you can change as much as you want, that doesn't disturb git, because git was created for it.
So I leave it up to you what you want to do, whether completely delete and restart or just revise.

Look also `git tag` for identify specific release version. So you can save several version. In your case *old-version* and *new-version* [tutorial](https://dev.to/neshaz/a-tutorial-for-tagging-releases-in-git-147e) just to show how powerful git is!

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
```

to commit all changes. Including deleted files.

```
git commit -m 'removed old files'
git push
```

Done.